# c++ how to make lock free stack push atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, free, atomic

I need to write a `void push(const T& val)` implementation for lock free stack.
The problem is that compare_exchange_weak expects non atomic `node*` but I must use `std::atomic<node*> next` field instead of regular `node* next`.
I tried to solve this problem by doing this

```
void push(const T& val) {
    node* new_node = new node(val);
    node* local_next = new_node->next.load();
    while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(local_next, new_node));
}
```

But creating if `local_next` makes things even worse. I tested 2 variants of code. The first one has non-atomic field `node* next` and I lost about 20-30 elements in the test code below. And using the second variant I got a deadlock.

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include "lock_free_stack.h"

using namespace std;

void test(lock_free_stack<int>& st, atomic<int>& sum) {
    st.push(1);
    shared_ptr<int> val(st.pop());
    while (val == nullptr) { }
    sum.store(sum.load() + *val);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    atomic<int> sum;
    sum.store(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        lock_free_stack<int> st;
        thread t1(test, ref(st), ref(sum));
        thread t2(test, ref(st), ref(sum));
        thread t3(test, ref(st), ref(sum));
        thread t4(test, ref(st), ref(sum));
        thread t5(test, ref(st), ref(sum));
        thread t6(test, ref(st), ref(sum));
        thread t7(test, ref(st), ref(sum));
        thread t8(test, ref(st), ref(sum));
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
        t5.join();
        t6.join();
        t7.join();
        t8.join();
    }
    if (sum.load() == 800) {
        cout << "CORRECT" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "TIME TO REWRITE STACK " << sum << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the code of my lock free stack (first variant):

```
#ifndef lock_free_stack_hard_lock_free_stack_h
#define lock_free_stack_hard_lock_free_stack_h

template <typename T>
class lock_free_stack {
private:
    struct node {
        node* next;
        std::shared_ptr<T> value;
        node (const T& val) : value(std::make_shared<T>(val)) { }
    };
    std::atomic<node*> head;
    std::shared_ptr<T> default_value;

public:
    lock_free_stack() : head(nullptr), default_value(std::make_shared<T>()) { }

    void push(const T& val) {
        node* new_node = new node(val);
        new_node->next = head.load();
        while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
        node* old_head = head.load();
        while (old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
        if (old_head) {
            return old_head->value;
        } else {
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

And the second variant:

```
#ifndef lock_free_stack_hard_lock_free_stack_h
    #define lock_free_stack_hard_lock_free_stack_h

    template <typename T>
    class lock_free_stack {
    private:
        struct node {
            std::atomic<node*> next;
            std::shared_ptr<T> value;
            node (const T& val) : value(std::make_shared<T>(val)) { }
        };
        std::atomic<node*> head;
        std::shared_ptr<T> default_value;

    public:
        lock_free_stack() : head(nullptr), default_value(std::make_shared<T>()) { }

        void push(const T& val) {
            node* new_node = new node(val);
            new_node->next = head.load();
            node* local_next = new_node->next.load();
            while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(local_next, new_node)); 
        }

        std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
            node* old_head = head.load();
            while (old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
            if (old_head) {
                return old_head->value;
            } else {
                return std::shared_ptr<T>();
            }
        }
    };

    #endif
```

So the final question is how to create that `local_next` correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: The example for [`compare_exchange_weak`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) actually implements a lock free `stack::push`.

Comment: @Barry, field `node* next` actually should look like `std::atomic<node*> next`

Comment: you may be hitting a compiler bug: [msvc](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/819819/std-atomic-compare-exchange-weak-has-spurious-write-which-can-cause-race-conditions), [clang](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2014-February/032833.html), and [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60272) all had problems compiling compare_exchange_* correctly. See [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) from cppreference.com.

Comment: @programmerjake compare_exchange really can't take the first argument if it's an atomic. It's not a bug

Comment: Unless there's something you're not telling us, start by making next non-atomic.

Comment: @Cubbi Like in the first variant? And what is the next step?

Comment: @Maksim given that your first example appears to be lifted straight from Listing 7.3 of Concurrency in Action, debug

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the test is the line `sum.store(sum.load() + *val);`

Use atomic ops, such as `sum += *val;`

Comment: Thank you, but still, how to implement this with `std::atomic<node*>` next?

Answer (score 1):

The first variant is garbage, because you can't guarantee atomicity on stores to node::next pointer. It would possible to use memory fence/barrier with non-atomic next-pointers, but I wouldn't trust such implementation.
Your second variant is more close to correct implementation.
However you forgot the most important thing from the push() CAS-loop:

```
void push(const T& val) {
    node* new_node = new node(val);
    new_node->next = head.load();
    node* local_next = new_node->next.load();
    while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(local_next, new_node)); 
}
```

Here the code allocates new node, loads and stores `head` pointer to `new_node->next`. Next, code saves already known stack `head` pointer value to `local_next`. (unnecessary step) Then code tries update stack `head` to `new_node` without updating `new_node->next`. This would be fine you were on singe core machine running single thread without pre-emption and the CAS would succeed 100% of time. ;)

When the CAS fails, it loads current fresh value of `head` into `local_next` and the code is stuck in infinite loop, because `new_node` will never be equal to `local_next`. So you got the last part wrong.

To make a functional CAS-loop the failing thread **must** reload and recompute what ever data it was trying to update. This means you must update `new_node->next` from `head` before re-trying the CAS.
This does not solve the ABA problem of CAS-loops, but I leave it out from my answer. I suggest reading more about CAS-operation and its pitfalls.

Because CAS operation does a load operation the fix is very simple, just store `local_next` to `new_node->next` after failing CAS.
Here is more valid (untested) version:

```
node* new_node = new node(val);
node* local_head = head.load();
new_node->next.store(local_head);
while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(local_head, new_node) {
    new_node->next.store(local_head);
}
```

You'll to do similiar thing to your pop() implementation.